# php exec logging parallel scripts

Tags: php

I got the following code:

```
$arg1 = 'somestring';
$myarray = [1,2,3,4,5];//my some array

foreach($myarray as $val){ 
    $E = exec("php myscript.php $arg1>/dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

So multiple instances of myscript.php work at the same time but some of them finish work with errors. I need to capture these errors. So how can I do that and keep the scripts run in parallel? Maybe I could add some error_reporting into myscript.php and dump the errors to a separate file somehow? Or is it possible to dump the output of php exec command to a file without parent process waiting for the output? Or should I use some 3rd party software for that purposes? Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: "Maybe I could add some error_reporting into myscript.php and dump the errors to a separate file somehow" good idea

Comment: Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script you can specify error logging and a file\loaction

```
ini_set("log_errors","1");
ini_set("error_log",__DIR__ . '/Errors.txt');
```

this will write the log to the same directory as the script file, if you want in it in the default directory remove the `__DIR__` part.

if you want one log per argument you could name it so:

```
    ini_set("error_log",__DIR__ . '/Errors'.$argv['2'].'.txt');
```

`$argv['2']` is he first`command line argument,`$argv['1']` is the file name